# Incorrect display PasswordChangeForm with additional html span tag

Tags: python, html, django

Im actually struggling with PasswordChangeForm in Django, but I don't know why label and input for password confirmation display on right side. I guess its an issue with span class helptext which should be smaller which dont disturb for pass.conf input. Look at my pic and code:  https://ibb.co/3CjTVrt

I've tried to apply some mods in CSS file with no results.

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request, 'Hasło zostało pomyślnie zmienione.')
            return redirect("flats_rent:zmień_hasło")
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
        response = render(request, 'flats_rent/settings.html', {'form': form})
        response.set_cookie('password_changed', 'true')
        return response
```

Expected: correct display of the form with 3 fields under themselves

Actual: just like in the pic

Comment: You need to show us how you are rendering the form.

Comment: Template: http://collabedit.com/37cf4

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is *included in the question itself*.